# How can I concatenate two user inputs in a flask app?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an app in flask, which has as user input two fields, however, I want to concatenate the inputs for querying the result in a sql table with sqlalchemy, however It keeps giving me the error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and ‘NoneType'

```
@search.route('/specie_results', methods=['GET','POST'])
def specie_results():
    form = SpecieSearchForm()
    genus = form.genus.data
    specie = form.specie.data
    species = genus + specie
    species_req = Files.get_by_species(species)
    return render_template ('specie_results.html', form=form, species_req=species_req)
```

This is my code for the form

```
class SpecieSearchForm(FlaskForm):
    genus = StringField('genus', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=64)])
    specie = StringField('specie', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('specie search’)
```

The code for the model:

```
class Files(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'files'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
    intensity = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=False)
    mz = db.Column(db.Float, unique=False, nullable=False)
    origin = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
    species = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=False, nullable=False)
    wd = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=False, nullable=False)
    time_created = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            db.session.add(self)
            db.session.commit()
    def delete(self):
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()

    @staticmethod
    def get_all():
        return Files.query.all()

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_species(species):
        return Files.query.filter_by(species=species).all()
```

I need to concatenate genus and specie to match the field species but I don’t know how to do it without the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form data seems to be empty. That's why its returning none type. You have already put the validators in the Class, so validate the form before working with the data.

Change the code to this and check.

```
@search.route('/specie_results', methods=['GET','POST'])
def specie_results():
    form = SpecieSearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        genus = form.genus.data
        specie = form.specie.data
        species = genus + specie
        species_req = Files.get_by_species(species)
    return render_template ('specie_results.html', form=form, species_req=species_req)
```